# Show specific div when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want specific divs to appear when specific links are pressed. This part works, but if you see any bugs with the code below, please don't hesitate to comment. I am keep asking me if I should replace `id` with `rel`.

**The problem**

The problem is that when page is loaded it loads all the divs. When a link is pressed the other dissapear. When page is loaded I only want `div1` to be shown. When another link is pressed, this should be hidden.

**JS**

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
              $('.current').removeClass('current');
              $(this).addClass('current');
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
     <a class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
     <a class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
     <a class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
     <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
     <!-- Content -->
</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
     <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

[Page can be found here.](http://vekvemedia.no/oppdrag/dokfilm/)

Any solutions?

Comment: define a css class `hidden` with `display: hidden;` and then use in your code on any div this class `class="showSingle hidden"` and only on div 1 not. on clicking a link use `$('.targetDiv').addClass('.hidden')` to hide all and `removeClass('hidden')` on the one, you want  to show

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asking for a code review and recommendations and is incomplete at as well all of which is off-topic.

Comment: @Olen - it might be helpful if you also posted your CSS...

Comment: This is also a duplicate of at least a dozen other questions as well.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Whether or not this question is a duplicate, I don't know--I don't follow this tag.  If it is, you should mark it as a duplicate and link to that duplicate.  However, I don't agree that this question is about a code review.  There is a very clear & specific problem statement with a description of the actual & intended behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do that:

- Use CSS classes for hidden/active states;
- Make sure the initial markup reflects the initial state;
- Use `data-` attributes;
- Use either `$` *or* `jQuery` everywhere;
- Either add fragment identifiers in a `href`, or use `button` elements;

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $(".showSingle").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.targetDiv').addClass("hidden");
    $("#div" + $(this).data('target')).removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}

.targetDiv {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <a class="showSingle active" data-target="1" href="#d1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="2" href="#d2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="3" href="#d3">Div 3</a>
</div>
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
  Uno
</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv hidden">
  Secundo
</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv hidden">
  Three
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

JQuery has an ready() function that can help you with this, because it executes once all the assets of your page have loaded.
Since you don't want any divs to show at first set their css style to `display:none`.
Then, use the ready function to diplay div1 at the beginning
    $(document).ready(function(){ $("#div1").show(); });

Comment: If you're going to _actually_ downvote a response, could you at least provide some context as to why. The above both responds to the question asked and provides an example. It may not be your preferred answer, but I fail to see how it's an invalid one...